# Determine if a software solution is 32 or 64-bit dependent?

Tags: architecture, x86

Assuming someone simply handed you a large software solution with no background, is their anyway to determine if a solution must be compiled/run as 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: For sake of clarity lets say it was C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C or C++, **I'd compile it with `gcc -Og -Wall`, once each with `-m32` and `-m64`**.  Or maybe `-Wextra`.  (Some warnings only work with optimization enabled, so a minimal optimization level that still compiles fast is preferable to `-O0`).

Also worth trying with clang, which has different and sometimes better warnings, and/or [libstdc++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/) instead of the usual-for-gcc libstdc++.

If one generates a lot more warnings than the other, especially about type mismatches or `printf` format strings, then it's probably not portable to that mode.

Many compiler warnings are designed to help catch code that isn't portable to 32-bit, or isn't portable to 64-bit.  The ideal situation of course (which warnings try to encourage) is code that works on both.

`int` and `long` are the same size in normal 32-bit x86 ABIs, but x86-64 System V has 64-bit `long` and pointers.  Windows x64 only has 64-bit pointers while `long` is still 32-bit, so that's another way to be non-portable.  Don't forget to compile for Windows as well as Linux if you want to get warnings for casting a pointer to `long` instead of `intptr_t`.  And/or to detect the assumption that `long` is a 64-bit type.

Looking for warnings about padding in struct layout might tell you something, if you think the original source was likely optimized to avoid padding in the intended mode.

---

This isn't foolproof (there are ways to be non-portable that won't generate warnings), and could be hard to use on ugly code that always generates a lot of warnings.

I don't think this is something you could automate, so I'm not sure this question is even on-topic for SO.

There are static-analysis for portability problems, I think, so beyond compiler warnings that would be what you'd want to look at if you're thinking about programmatically detecting this.

Comment: This was very informational and just the kind of answer I was looking for, thank you sir!